# Quarkus set default database

Tags: oracle, datasource, quarkus

I have 2 named datasources in my quarkus app, lets call it A and B:

- quarkus.datasource.A.db-kind=oracle
- quarkus.datasource.B.db-kind=oracle

Because of this everytime the app started I get this notification :

> WARN :  Unable to determine a database type for default datasource

Is there a way to set this default? I cant rename or remove the names from the datasources

Comment: What do you meant by "I can't rename or remove the names from the datasources"? Regardless, anywhere you have referenced `A`, just use the `default` (unnamed) one — or vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources, you should use one of them as the default datasource - i.e. not have it named.

Something like:

```
# this one is the default datasource as it is not named
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle 
quarkus.datasource.B.db-kind=oracle
```

Comment: so... theres no way to set it ?

Comment: Nope, see updated answer